# adding info to DataNavigateUrlFormatString not in the datagrid

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a datagrid that has a DataNavigateUrlFormatString that passes info on to the next page when the user clicks on the link.  However I am trying to add some functionality to the next page and want to add some data to the url that is not in the bound columns.  Is there a way to do this?   Right now it looks like

```
 DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~/cakes/PaymentHistory.aspx?id={0}"
```

and I would like it to look like

```
 DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~/Taxes/PaymentHistory.aspx?id={0}&year="
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~/Taxes/PaymentHistory.aspx?id={0}&year={1}"
```

and then retrieve like this :

```
Dim id  As String = Request.QueryString("id")
Dim year As String = Request.QueryString("year")
```